# changing file name and extension using loop

Tags: python

I need to change the name and extension of a series of files. The names are currently 'tmax.##.txt', but I need it to be 'tmax_##.txt'. Then, I want to change the .txt extension to .asc. I've tried the below code and the first loop works as expected to produce 'tmax_01'. The second loop runs, but produces unexpected results, 't'.

```
list_raw = 'tmax.01.txt', 'tmax.02.txt', 'tmax.03.txt'

for i in list_raw:
    list_conv = i.replace('.','_')

for i in list_conv:
list_final = i.replace('_txt','.asc')
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You are just assigning new values to a variable in each iteration of the loop. What you want to do is create a new list from the modified elements of an existing list, which is best done with a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
list_raw = ['tmax.01.txt', 'tmax.02.txt', 'tmax.03.txt']
list_final = [i.replace(".", "_").replace("_txt", ".asc") for i in list_raw]
```

Note that you can do this, as in my example, in one step - there is no reason to iterate over the list twice, and produce an intermediate list, which is inefficient.

You could also do `i.replace(".", "_", 1)` to only replace the first `.`, and avoid having to do the awkward hack with the file extension. However, I would personally use `i[:-4].replace(".", "_") + ".asc"` - that is, cut off the existing extension with a slice, replace the `.`s, and then add the new extension.

If the extensions are likely to vary in length, you may want to look into the `os.path` module, as suggested by [sotapme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14665716/722121).

Answer (score 2):

Because you're talking of files it may be worth using `os.path` as it's likely that the next part of your code will be to manipulate these or other files. (just guessing)

```
os.path.splitext('afile.txt')[0] + '.asc'
```

Gives

```
'afile.asc'
```

Comment: +1, this is a good way to split the extension off, although it may be overkill if, as implied, the extension will always be `.txt`.

Comment: I agree - But I've lost count of the times I've said to myself "It's only for .txt files and then I have to add that other special file an d another' - I think by using ``os.path`` that it's more explicit that we're talking filenames although it's a very moot point given how specific the OP has been and of course the ease of using ``.replace`` makes it so trivial.

Comment: This is true, it's generally better to design more robustly, those kind of specifications tend to end up not holding over time, and adding the flexibility here doesn't cost anything.

Comment: Then again [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it) a difficult balancing act.

Answer (score 1):

In the first loop: -

```
for i in list_raw:
    list_conv = i.replace('.','_')
```

Your `list_conv` contains a `str` object. And it will contain the last element in the list with the appropriate replacement.

Then in your 2nd loop: -

```
for i in list_conv:
    list_final = i.replace('_txt','.asc')
```

You are just iterating over string sequence, which will give you 1 character at a time. And `list_final` will contain the last character with the appropriate replacement done.

Since the last character in `tmax_03_txt` is `t`, that is why you got `t`.

---

If you want to do the replacement on each element of the list, then you can use `list comprehension`, and chaning of method invocation: -

```
>>> list_raw = ['tmax.01.txt', 'tmax.02.txt', 'tmax.03.txt']
>>> [elem.replace('.', '_').replace('_txt', '.asc') for elem in list_raw]
16: ['tmax_01.asc', 'tmax_02.asc', 'tmax_03.asc']
```

Comment: +1, This is a good explanation of why the original fails, although your example of a solution doesn't do all that is wanted by the OP.

Comment: @Lattyware.. Yeah, actually I forgot to change the extension. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you could use the [string method rsplit](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip).

```
list_raw = ['tmax.01.txt', 'tmax.02.txt', 'tmax.03.txt']
list_final = [filename.rsplit('.',1)[0] + '.ext' for filename in list_raw]
```

Where ext is the new extension.  The 1 in rsplit() indicates that only the rightmost '.' will act as split point.